# How to avoid repeated CRUD code for each SQLite table?

Tags: c++, sqlite, crud, repeat

My SQLite3 database consists of 10+ tables. Each table has own unique record class and CRUD wrappers.

Problem: When writing the CRUD wrapper for each table, I just Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V the code, substituting class names and its members. This repeated monotonous work feels wrong.

Is there better way to do this than the repeated code below? If not, why?

```
#include <sqlite3.h>

sqlite3 *db;

int get_author_callback(void *retval, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);
int get_definition_callback(void *retval, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName);

class author{
    std::string author_id;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string second_name;
    std::string billing_number;
};

// CRUD for SQL table "author"
void create_author(author* my_author);
void read_author(const std::string author_id, author* my_author);
void update_author(const std::string author_id, author* my_author);
void delete_author(const std::string author_id);
void list_authors(std::vector<author>* my_authors); // SELECT * FROM author;

class definition{
    std::string definition_id;
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
    double use_cost;
    std::string use_cost_currency;
};

// CRUD for SQL table "definition"
void create_definition(definition* my_definition);
void read_definition(const std::string definition_id, definition* my_definition);
void update_definition(const std::string definition_id, definition* my_definition);
void delete_definition(const std::string definition_id);
void list_definitions(std::vector<definition>* my_definition); // SELECT * FROM definition;
```